# how to create text field with a button click ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to IOS programming.
I want to make text-field with a simple `button`. like, When we click the button Create-Field `(btnCreateField)`, it should make a new `textfield`. The number of times we click the button the number of fields should be created.
like when we call

```
-(IBAction)btaCreateField;
```

e.g; we create row in table etc or div etc in php and .net same like that how to make a text field in objective c ios....
Please give your solution.
thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Please see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). What have you tried doing? Show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)btnCreateField
{
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40)];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;    
    textField.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
}
```

Comment: 'assigning to id from incompatible type *const __strong' it give this warning. 
This current code is working, But its showing warning on textField.delegate = self; and sir how can we drop the next textfield below this one like when the button is pressed second time, it will place the next textFeild above this one, how to place the next below.

Comment: I would like you to figure that out @user2752300. It will be a good exercise ;) (And technically, this question has been answered). HINT: Th first two digits after `CGRectMake` control the position of the UITextfield. Play around with it and see how it works.

Comment: ok, I know this question is answered i have searched those as well thanks for being cooperative. but can u just suggest if i try some loop?

Comment: Yes, you could try using a `for` loop to change the x,y coordinates in CGRectMake. You should close this question off (mark accept), ask another one named "Programmatically create multiple UITextFields in different positions". Post the code that you have in the IBAction, explain how you think you would do change the positions, and then ask for help with explanations. I will see you there if I have time! Good luck @user2752300.